# Is it possible to add transparancy to a light in After Effects?

Tags: 3d, adobe-after-effects, lighting-effects

Title says most of it. I want to have a light slowly fade away and make the 3D cube look 2D (it looks 2D when the light is off). In the transform options there doesn't seem to be a opacity effect slider. 
[image]

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert in after effects, but couldn't you just animate the brightness / intensity of the light all the way down to zero (= off) to achieve the effect that you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately when you turn a light 'off' in After Effects it gives a pitch black result. It doesn't function the same way as transparency.

Comment: In that case, I suspect that you need to add an AMBIENT light source to the scene to give the desired final colour. This could either be static (in terms of brightness, so it would be there all the time) or it could grow brighter as your spot light grows darker.

Comment: Good idea, I tried it but I can't get it to match the desired color 100%. With 100% on intensity it doesn't reflect the light I type in accurately. I used a non-3D orange solid for now and fiddled with the settings to just cover the 3D shape. It's a bit hacky but it works

Comment: The ambien light has to be white, you need to fade your lights out and fade the ambient in at the same time.